# Can I set a single thread's priority above 15 for a normal priority process?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, timing

I have a data acquisition application running on Windows 7, using VC2010 in C++.  One thread is a heartbeat which sends out a change every .2 seconds to keep-alive some hardware which has a timeout of about .9 seconds.  Typically the heartbeat call takes 10-20ms and the thread spends the rest of the time sleeping.

Occasionally however there will be a delay of 1-2 seconds and the hardware will shut down momentarily.  The heartbeat thread is running at THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL which is 15 for a normal priority process.   My other threads are running at normal priority, although I use a DLL to control some other hardware and have noticed with Process Explorer that it starts several threads running at level 15.

I can't track down the source of the slow down but other theads in my application are seeing the same kind of delays when this happens.  I have made several optimizations to the heartbeat code even though it is quite simple, but the occasional failures are still happening.  Now I wonder if I can increase the priority of this thread beyond 15 without specifying REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS for the entire process.  If not, are there any downsides I should be aware of to using REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS?  (Other than this heartbeat thread, the rest of the application doesn't have real-time timing needs.)

(Or does anyone have any ideas about how to track down these slowdowns...not sure if the source could be in my app or somewhere else on the system).

Update: So I hadn't actually tried passing 31 into my AfxBeginThread call and turns out it ignores that value and sets the thread to normal priority instead of the 15 that I get with THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL.

Update: Turns out running the Disk Defragmenter is a good way to cause lots of thread delays.  Even running the process at REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS and the heartbeat thread at THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL (level 31) doesn't seem to help.  Next thing to try is calling AvSetMmThreadCharacteristics("Pro Audio")

Update: Scheduling heartbeat thread as "Pro Audio" does work to increase the thread's priority beyond 15 (Base=1, Dynamic=24) but it doesn't seem to make any real difference when defrag is running.  I've been able to correlate many of the slowdowns with the disk defragmenter so turned off the weekly scan.  Still can't explain some delays so we're going to increase to a 5-10 second watchdog timeout.

Comment: It scares me when people use words like "heartbeat" and "shut down for safety reasons" in a programming question about Windows.  :)  It's certainly not an RTOS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system

Comment: I think your watchdog is to strict. On an RTOS 500ms are plenty, but on Windows anything below 15 seconds is risky. If you have control over your watchdog then I suggest to make the timeout longer or make it shut down only if it misses a certain number of your triggers.

Comment: Question: What is the time after which your hardware will shut down?

Comment: Will shut down if no heartbeat is received .5 seconds after the last one.  I like your comment about increasing the timeout and is something we will probably do, but I wanted to try to optimize from the software side first.  I don't think we can go to 15 seconds but maybe 5 seconds

Comment: So you are triggering the watchdog more often than every 500ms, right? Just checking.

Comment: You can set the priority to 16 if your pc volume control has a setting of '11'.

Comment: updated the question with more precise timing number.  heartbeat is sent every .2 seconds and watchdog timeout is .9 seconds

Comment: @Fozi: Out of curiousity: Is there any kind of reference for this threshold on Windows of 15 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you could, increasing the priority will not help.  The highest priority runnable thread gets the processor at all times.

Most likely there is some extended interrupt processing occurring while interrupts are disabled. Interrupts effectively work at a higher priority than any thread.

It could be video, network, disk, serial, USB, etc., etc.  It will take some insight to selectively disable or use an alternate driver to see if the problem system hesitation is affected.  Once you find that, then figuring out a way to prevent it might range from trivial to impossible depending on what it is.

Without more knowledge about the system, it is hard to say.  Have you tried running it on a *different* PC?

Comment: thanks for the vote of confidence :)  i have run on a few different computers but generally always have the same software and drivers installed.  I will think about what I can disable and run but will be hard to track down since problem is intermittent, seems to be happening every day or two.  thanks!

Comment: the reason i'm hoping it would make a difference is that this other hardware dll has 5 out of 7 of its thread at level 15.  When things get busy I'd rather my thread take priority over them.  However if it is a hardware interrupt like you suggest that wouldn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Officially you can't use REALTIME threads in a process which does not have the REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS.

Unoficially you could play with the undocumented `NtSetInformationThread`
see:
http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/NtSetInformationThread.html

But since I have not tried it, I don't have any more info about this.

On the other hand, as it was said before, you can never be sure that the OS will not take its time when your thread's quantum will expire. Certain poorly written drivers are often the cause of such latency.

Otherwise there is a software which can tell you if you have misbehaving kernel parts:
http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml

Comment: If you find a case where DPC latency will increase drastically, then thread priorities cant help you since DPCs (Delayed Procedure Calls) run at higher "priority" (in reality IRQL) than anything in user mode...

Answer (score 0):

I would try using CreateWaitableTimer() & SetWaitableTimer() and see if they are subject to the same preemption problems.